# Procedure to check if list is cyclic (Scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, r5rs, cyclic

Is there a built-in procedure to check if a list is cyclic in Scheme (R5RS)? And when is a list cyclic (per definition)? I have tried to find some procedure that checks this, and how it is implemented, but I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is [circular per definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_vs._linearly_linked) if the `cdr` of the tail (last element) points to the head of the list. However, you can also have a circular list where the `cdr` of the tail points to an arbitrary element in the list. [A good algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) to detect a circular list is the tortoise and hare algorithm. An example implementation is given at [this page](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special:DownloadCode/Floyd%27s_cycle-finding_algorithm_(Scheme)&oldid=16654).

The code is as follows (**credit to the author of the page linked above**):

**Edit**: I modified the code because it contained an error pointed out by Sylwester.

```
(define (has-cycle-h slow-ls fast-ls)
  (cond
   ((null? fast-ls) #f)
   ((null? (cdr fast-ls)) #f)
   ((eq? slow-ls fast-ls) #t)
   (else (has-cycle-h (cdr slow-ls) (cddr fast-ls)))))

(define (has-cycle? ls)
  (cond
    ((null? ls) #f)
    (else (has-cycle-h ls (cdr ls)))))


;; Create cyclic list
(define l (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))))
(set-cdr! (cdr (cdr (cdr l))) l)
;; Results in:
;+---+    +---+   +---+    +---+
;| 1 +--->| 2 +-->| 3 +--->| 4 |
;+-+-+    +---+   +---+    +-+-+
;  ^                         |  
;  |                         |  
;  +-------------------------+  

(has-cycle? l) ; Evaluates to #t


;; Create list
(define l (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))))
;; Make it circular by pointing the tail to the second element.
(set-cdr! (cdr (cdr (cdr l))) (cdr l))
;; Results in:
;+---+    +---+   +---+    +---+ 
;| 1 +--->| 2 +-->| 3 +--->| 4 |
;+---+    +-+-+   +---+    +-+-+
;           ^                |  
;           |                |  
;           +----------------+
(has-cycle? l) ; Evaluatores to #t

; Regular list
(has-cycle? '(1 1 1 1 1 1 1)) ; Evaluates to #f
```

There is no BIF for detecting  a circular list.

Comment: `(eq? (car slow-ls) (car fast-ls))` seems wrong. It should be `(eq? slow-ls fast-ls)`. Try it with `'(#f #f #f)`

Comment: That seems to be true. I just copy pasted the code. I will update! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is `circular-list?` predicate in SRFI 1. The definition of circular list in SRFI 1 is: "A circular list is a value such that for every n>=0, cdr^n(x) is a pair." It means that there is no end of the list. The first pair of the circular list does not need to be part of a cycle. It is enough that one eventually by following the cdrs reaches a cycle.

SRFI 1 has this description on non-circular lists:

```
(not (circular-list? x)) = (or (proper-list? x) (dotted-list? x))
```

SRFI 1 is not in R5RS per se, but all implementations I know of come with srfi 1 included. Note that if srfi1 is implemented in the runtime, the `circular-list?` predicate from srfi 1 could be faster than a Scheme implementation of the tortoise-and-hare algorithm. Benchmark your implementation of choice to find out how your implementation behaves.

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#circular-list-p